# eucalyptus installation centos7

Tags: repository, centos7, yum, eucalyptus

i need your support to install eucalyptus centos7.9
[FATAL] Eucalyptus installation failed
Eucalyptus installation failed. Please consult /var/log/euca-install-05.15.2023-02.07.56.log for details.

log :

```
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failure talking to yum: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from midonet: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.\nhttp://builds.midonet.org/midonet-5.2/stable/el7/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#6 - \"Could not resolve host: builds.midonet.org; Unknown error\""}
host1                      : ok=64   changed=29   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=33   rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Could you help me to resolve this issue.

BR
Aymen

i try temporarily disable but not worked

```
yum-config-manager --disable midonet-misc
```